# MongoDB - too much data for sort() with no index error using C# driver on a small record set

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting

I see others have had this problem without a definitive answer. In my case I am using the C# driver. My sort looks like this:

```
 cursor.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("Location", "BusinessLine", "Manager", "TeamLead", "AgentName", "EventDate"));
```

With a collection of 32,201 records, it runs fine. Anything over that, I get this error. I've tried indexes on any and off my sort variable and nothing changes the outcome. Any ideas?

Comment: It is limited to 32meg of RAM, why do you want to solve this without an index?

Comment: What exact index did you try?  and what is your entire query?  And the definitive answer is here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Sorted Documents

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the batch size. Before iterating through a cursor you must set the batch size. In this case, I set it to cursor.BatchSize = 30000; and it worked fine.

Comment: That means that you are returning 30,000 records, if they fit in 16meg of RAM otherwsie you return the next closest thing. Batchsize is likely what your not looking for